# Can we always find coordinates on a surface such that $K=K(u-v)$?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, riemann-surfaces, surfaces

Let $(M^2,g)$ be a 2-dimensional Riemannian manifold. For any point $p\in M^2$ can we always find coordinates $(u,v)$ in a neighborhood $U$ of $p$ such that the Gaussian curvature is only a function of $u\pm v$, i.e, $K=K(u\pm v)$ ?

Comment: Near a nondegenerate critical point of Gauss curvature, clearly the answer is no.

Comment: Near a regular point of Gauss curvature, clearly the answer is yes.

Comment: @BenMcKay Thanks. In the affirmative case, do we have an idea about how to construct such a system of coordinates ?

Comment: Near a regular point of Gauss curvature $K$, i.e. where $dK\ne 0$, take any function $v$ with nonzero differential linearly independent of $dK$ at that point. Let $u=K+v$. Near degenerate critical points, I am not sure.

Comment: A necessary condition: at any critical point, the Hessian $D^2K$ becomes well defined (independent of coordinates or metric), and must have rank $0$ or $1$. If rank $0$, i..e vanishing Hessian, then $D^3K$ becomes well defined and must have rank $0$ or $1$. If $D^2K$ has rank $1$, then $D^3K$ becomes defined along the null space of $D^2K$, and must vanish there, along with all higher $D^n K$ for all $n\ge 3$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Curvature is a smooth function on the surface, and locally, any smooth negative function can serve as a curvature of some surface (M. S. Berger, Riemannian structure of prescribed Gaussian curvature for compact 2-manifolds, J. Differential Geom. 5 (1971), 325-332.)

So the question is whether for an arbitrary smooth function there exists
a coordinate system such that the function depends on only one coordinate. The answer is certainly negative, since the function can have critical points.